# stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document with loops

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to navigate through a system that has multiple tabs on the page, each tab has multiple page links on them. I know this has to do with the elements being removed from DOM but I'm not sure exactly how to resolve this issue with my scenario.

```
        //Get all the elements in the top tab section
        IList<IWebElement> tabIndex = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@class='TabList ClearFix']//a[@tabindex=-1]"));
        //The first page of the frist tab is already accessed
        //Get all the page links that are in the left navigation bar, click on the page and then move onto the next one
        //Once the last page is accessed, move to the next tab and repeat.
        foreach (IWebElement element in tabIndex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element.Text.ToString());
            IList<IWebElement> leftIndex = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='LeftMenu']//a[@tabindex=-1]"));
            foreach (IWebElement lElement in leftIndex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lElement.Text.ToString());
            }
            element.Click();
        }
```

I'm getting the exception at: `Console.WriteLine(element.Text.ToString());`
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @Forty Two: OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stale element: you are finding an element resulting in an object > page changes/reloads > you are trying to use that object.

Your main issue is that you are doing a `click` action in a `foreach` loop on a list of objects previously found, those element objects are lost on page change/reload.

You need to make sure the page does not change between finding the element and using it in for an action.

> Do not do action in a loop that could change the page using objects from outside the loop

Options:
 - count tabs and use find in the loop by index
 - find all tabs, save some `attributes` in a list and use those attributes to find each tab in your loop
 - use a selector to identify tab based on a current tab, like a selector for the next unopened tab

Comment: So, instead of working inside loops, Save hrefs of each of the tabs/pages in lists and then iterate through those lists?

Answer (score 0):

Just doing something simple like moving the element collection scrape into the loop should fix it. That way at the top of the loop, the page is scraped again.

```
// Get all the elements in the top tab section
//The first page of the frist tab is already accessed
//Get all the page links that are in the left navigation bar, click on the page and then move onto the next one
//Once the last page is accessed, move to the next tab and repeat.
foreach (IWebElement element in driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@class='TabList ClearFix']//a[@tabindex=-1]")))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Text.ToString());
    foreach (IWebElement lElement in driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='LeftMenu']//a[@tabindex=-1]")))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(lElement.Text.ToString());
    }
    element.Click();
}
```