# StaleElementReferenceException when crawling a website using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I am using `Selenium` to crawl a web page with lots of inner links.
I have the following code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WebScraper {
    //list to save visited links
    static List<String> linkAlreadyVisited = new ArrayList<String>();
    static String userName = "user";
    static String password = "passw";
    static String mainPage = "https://web/";
    WebDriver driver;
    //    public WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    String loginPage = "https://web/Login";

    public WebScraper(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        WebScraper webScraper = new WebScraper(driver);
        webSrcapper.openTestSite();
        webSrcapper.login(userName, password);
        driver.navigate().to(mainPage);

        driver.get(mainPage);
        // start recursive linkText
        new WebScraper(driver).linkTest();
    }

    public static boolean isElementStale(WebElement e) {
        try {
            e.isDisplayed();
            return false;
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ex) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void linkTest() {
        // loop over all the a elements in the page
        for (WebElement link : driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"))) {
            // Check if link is displayed and not previously visited
            if (!isElementStale(link)
                    && !linkAlreadyVisited.contains(link.getText())) {
                // add link to list of links already visited
                linkAlreadyVisited.add(link.getText());
                System.out.println(link.getText());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    link.click();

                } catch (Exception ex) {

//                    String id = link.getAttribute("id");
                    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("$('#id').click();");

                }
                // call recursiveLinkTest on the new page
                new WebScraper(driver).linkTest();

            } else {
continue;
            }
        }
        driver.navigate().back();
    }

    /**
     * //     * Open the test website. //
     */
    public void openTestSite() {

        driver.navigate().to(loginPage);
    }

    public void login(String username, String Password) {

        WebElement userName_editbox = driver.findElement(By.id("IDToken1"));
        WebElement password_editbox = driver.findElement(By.id("IDToken2"));
        WebElement submit_button = driver.findElement(By.name("Login.Submit"));

        userName_editbox.sendKeys(username);
        password_editbox.sendKeys(Password);
        submit_button.click();

    }
}
```

This code works for around one hour and then I get a `StaleElementReferenceException`. As there are lots of links on the webpage, I can simply ignore that link and it's not that important to me to follow every single link.

So, I tried to escape this exception with the `else clause` including `continue;` command. But it doesn't work. My question is why? I just want to go to the next link.

In the meantime, as the code takes a long time to run, I don't know where exactly it happens (also, I have seen that sometimes the code runs differently, that is the order of the links are not always the same, so I can't debug easily) and I can't check that specific link.

I tried different solutions that I found on the websites. For example, `Thread.sleep` after and before clicking on a link and `new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` .

Does any one have any solution for this problem?

Comment: for debugging purposes you could do a try-catch, where you catch `StaleElementReferenceException` and either set a breakpoint for debugging or at least print the problem causing link to `System.out`

Comment: Also.. are you sure you want to open the links recursively? you know that you have implemented a depth-first-search which is probably not the best solution if you want to crawl the web. you will just always follow the first link you find and unless you find a page with no links, you will never look at the second link on any page.

Comment: i would instead recommend a FIFO queue where you store all the found links and every time you have processed a page `poll` the next item from the list. also transform the `List` into a `Set`, as it has a runtime of `O(1)` instead of `O(n)` (and `n` can get pretty big in your case)

Comment: Bad code, beginner mistake. There are a lot of questions with this exception, `don't do actions that can change the page in a loop`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091311/stale-element-reference-element-is-not-attached-to-the-page-document-with-loops    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573231/i-am-getting-nullpointer-exception-when-i-perform-click-for-the-same-webelemen

Answer (score 0):

This could work. Please note that I programmed it in the browser and not an actual IDE, so excuse any typos I made.

What I have changed: We only use a single instance of the class `WebScraper`. This will go easier on out memory. We won't search depth first, but breath first instead by using a `Queue<String>`. Every time we find a new link, its url gets added to `Queue<String> links`. After that we take link by link and crawl it.

You might need to make some adjustments, as we don't call `link.click()` anymore, so maybe you'll need to fix the link before adding it (if `https://stackoverflow.com` is missing for example)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WebScraper {
    public static final long WEBSITE_LOAD_TIME = 1000;
    //list to save visited links
    static List<String> linkAlreadyVisited = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String mainPage;
    private WebDriver driver;
    public static final String loginPage = "https://web/Login";
    public Queue<String> links = new LinkedList<>();
    public Set<String> visitedLinks = new LinkedHashSet(); // linked so we can later on determine which links where visited in which order

    public WebScraper(WebDriver driver, String page, String userName, String password) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        WebScraper webSrcaper = new WebScraper(driver, "user", "passw");
        webSrcaper.login(userName, password);
        webSrcaper.start("https://web/");
    }

    public void start(String page) {
        links.add(page);
        while (!links.isEmpty()) {
            crawlPage(links.poll());
        }
    }

    public void crawlPage(String address) {
        System.out.println("visiting page \"" + linkAddress+"\"");  
        driver.navigate().to(address);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(WEBSITE_LOAD_TIME);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        visitedLinks.add(linkAddress);
        for (WebElement link : driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"))) {
            try {
                String linkAddress = link.getAttribute("href");
                if (!visitedLinks.contains(linkAddress)) {
                    System.out.println("found link \"" + linkAddress+"\"");
                    links.add(linkAddress);
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            } catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                System.out.println("link became stale and is therefore ignored."); 
            }
        }
    }

    public void login(String username, String Password) {
        driver.navigate().to(loginPage);
        WebElement userName_editbox = driver.findElement(By.id("IDToken1"));
        WebElement password_editbox = driver.findElement(By.id("IDToken2"));
        WebElement submit_button = driver.findElement(By.name("Login.Submit"));

        userName_editbox.sendKeys(username);
        password_editbox.sendKeys(Password);
        submit_button.click();
    }
}
```

Feel free to edit my answer if I have made any typos or logical errors. I am not able to test my solution at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your time and code. I have two main questions about the code. Firstly, how can I download the files if I face one. In the previous version, I clicked on the link and it caused downloading a file, if there was any. But now, I think clicking on a link may harm the code. Doesn't it?
Should I firstly find all the links and then go through the links and click on them?
Secondly, the start(page) function, has an empty list of links.

Comment: can you post the html of said link?

Comment: So, I added the mainPage as the starting point to be able to start crawling. But I'm getting "IndexOutOfBounds: Index: 25, Size: 0". I don't know why. I'm struggling with that.

Comment: Sorry, due to data security, I'm not allowed to make the crawled website public.

Comment: Let me know which kind of information you need, and I'll let you know.

Comment: i forgot one line in the start(); method. that exception should be gone now. like i said, i never run the code myself ;) just post the link html. what kind of link is it? there must be some way to tell the browser to start the download. and as soon as i know how we can find a way of downloading the data

Comment: i am talking only about the <a something> element

Comment: here is an example of the a element:
     <p> <p>Customer Engagement Process</p><p>...forward.</p><p>For more information</p><ul><li><a href="https://blah/download" target="_blank"></a><a href="https://blah/af/download" target="_blank">Process Overview</a> and</li><li><a href="https://blah/view.php?id=1213"></a><a href="https://lblah/view.php?id=1213" target="_blank">Training Presentations.</a><br></li></ul>

Comment: it looks to me like this should actually work with the code i gave you. did you try to run it again? did you encounter other errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158585/discussion-between-lonely-neuron-and-user1419243).

Comment: I continued in the chat room, but are you there?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a slightly better solution for finding fresh `webElement` most of the times. I created a wrapper function over `driver.findElement()`.

```
 public WebElement findFreshElement(By locator){ // To handle stale Element reference exception
      WebElement webElement = null;
      int attempts =0;
      while(attempts < 10){
      try {
          wait.hardWait(2);
          webElement = driver.findElement(locator);
          webElement.isDisplayed();
          break;
      } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
          logMessage("⚠ Stale Element Reference Exception ... Refinding element after 2 seconds.. ");
          attempts+=1;
      }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
           logMessage("❌ [ELEMENT NOT FOUND] : You might have to update the locator:-" + locator);
        attempts+=1;     
        }
      }
      return webElement;
  
    }
```

`wait.hardWait(2)` is a `Thread.Sleep` wrapper method. Since, `hardwait` is used, its not the best solution, but it is better than just checking the element state. This method actually **returns a fresh element reference**.